# Unable to swap out img element for SVG

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have some code that loops through SVG `img` elements and attempts to swap out the images for inline SVG code:

```
(function () {
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    var i;

    for(i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        var imageEl = el[i],
            imgSrc = imageEl.src;

        if(typeof imgSrc != 'undefined' && imgSrc.match(/\.svg$/)) {   
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            request.open('GET', imgSrc, true);
            request.send();

            request.onload = function () {
                console.log(newImage);
                imageEl.outerHTML = request.responseText;
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

However, this returns: `Uncaught NoModificationAllowedError: Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node.`

I'm a bit unsure if why this is occurring. I'm trying to reproduce the `replaceWith` function from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using making async false and changed the code slightly:

```
(function () {
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    var i;

    for(i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        var imageEl = el[i],
            imgSrc = imageEl.src;

        if(typeof imgSrc != 'undefined' && imgSrc.match(/\.svg$/)) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    imageEl.outerHTML = request.responseText;
                }
            }

            request.open('GET', imgSrc, false);
            request.send();
        }
    }

})();
```